# Spark window function without orderBy

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame with columns `a, b` for which I want to partition the data by `a` using a window function, and then give unique indices for `b`

```
val window_filter = Window.partitionBy($"a").orderBy($"b".desc)
withColumn("uid", row_number().over(window_filter))
```

But for this use-case, ordering by `b` is unneeded and may be time consuming. How can I achieve this without ordering?

Comment: I realized I can orderBy the same column as partitionBy, but I'm not sure this is better.

Comment: you could order By literal 1 as shown below `Window.partitionBy($"a").orderBy(lit(1))`

Comment: What is your end goal? if you just want a unique id you can use monotonically_increasing_id instead of using the window funciton

Comment: @rogue-one if you do explain(true) you would see that it still does the sorting even with lit(1), I am not sure how much it will save...

Comment: @rogue-one end goal is to take arbitrary 1000 (or different constant) for each value in `a`

Comment: Hi @DeanLa I have a trivial version using `groupBy`, not sure if performance is worse: `df.groupBy(col("a")).agg(collect_list("b") as "all_b").withColumn("sample_b", my_random_sample("all_b")).select("a", explode(df("sample_b")))`

Answer (score 2):

`row_number()` without order by or with order by constant has non-deterministic behavior and may produce different results for the same rows from run to run due to parallel processing. The same may happen if the order by column does not change, the order of rows may be different from run to run and you will get different results.